# Refreshing browser add duplicate entry in database - php

Tags: php

I have a form in which user input some details and then click a save button to save the data on database. Now after click save if I refresh the page browser ask for resend. If we resend it then duplicate entry available in database. My database insert process is on same page. Can it possible to prevent resend after completing process on single page?

Thank You in advance

Comment: A well known solution for this problem is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you can redirect users after submitting and performing `insert` using `header("Location: somepage.php")`
2. you can (an i think should) use unique constraint in the db (e.g. for Postgres: `CONSTRAINT c_name UNIQUE (field_name)`)

Comment: Yes I know it. But can it possible this on a single page?

Comment: @Hardik the second option can be done in the same page as the insert

Answer (score 1):

One way is to invalidate the browser's cache by adding something like this to your PHP code:

```
 header( "Expires: Mon, 20 Dec 1998 01:00:00 GMT" );
 header( "Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT" );
 header( "Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
 header( "Pragma: no-cache" );
```

Comment: Does this actually tell the browser that the form data must be forgotten, or just the form HTML itself?

Answer (score 0):

No. Add a hidden field to the form that uniquely identifies the transaction and refuse the update if you see the same one.

That, or preform a redirect to another page in order to turn it into a GET request.